# Decking boards with grooves on both sides

Tags: deck, decking

I'm planning a deck build in the UK. The 3 biggest DIY retailers here all seem to sell decking boards which are grooved on both sides. There's a lot of mixed advice from the videos/instructions I've been checking out. Some say it's a matter of preference and others say you must absolutely put the grooved side down: http://www.build.com.au/should-decking-grooves-face-or-down

So, should I be looking elsewhere for boards or does it really matter?

Comment: You should follow the manufacturer's installation instructions. Not doing so could void any warranties, and/or reduce the useful life of the product.

Comment: @Tester101 is 100% correct. Go to the source for the information.

Comment: Sure, but the manufacturers here just say in their instructional videos that it's a matter of preference. I'm curious about people outside the UK who would have more experience in decking

Comment: The grooved boards are not common outside of the UK. At least not in North America. They are very few and far between. (In fact, I can only recall ever seeing them on thermally modified decking)

Comment: Good to know, thanks. I finally found smooth boards here. Very difficult to get good quality wood for decks here!